# Crown ether complex formation with cesium carbonate

Tags: coordination-compounds, ionic-compounds, ethers

I am searching for some papers which form complex between crown ether and caesium carbonate. But Most papers only use caesium carbonate as a base in the synthesis of crown ether, not ionic compound for chelation. Can't caesium carbonate form complex with crown ether? Does the fact that caesium carbonate is a base have to do with it? More generally, does the anion of ionic compound also affect the formation of complex between crown ether and metal cation?

Comment: Size matters in crown ethers. You have to find the right crown ether where Cs ion can fit. The are scores of articles on this topic. Did you try Google Scholar?

Comment: @AChem I know there are appropriate sizes of crown ether according to the target cation. But I wonder that despite of right size of cavity whether cesium carbonate cannot form complex. Most papers uses cesium chloride or cesium nitrate. Does the anion 'carbonate' or basicity of cesium carbonate matter?

Comment: Krang Lee, Yes, the anions can significantly affect extraction / crown ether's selecitivity. Anion effect on selectivity in crown ether extraction of alkali metal cations
Uriel Olsher, Matthew G. Hankins, Youn Doo Kim, and Richard A. Bartsch
Cite this: J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1993, 115, 8, 3370–3371

Comment: If nobody has specifically studied CsCO3 and crown ether complexation it could be a small and useful publication for you just like one cited in J. Am. Chem. Soc. This is why countless Chem Dept. in the world are still alive and thriving. Not all is known or published.